# Custom class for Chart Tooltip with Amcharts

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if thee is a way to link the chart tooltip to a custom class to create the styling that we want. The library seems limited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940803/visualize-table-on-tooltip-with-amcharts

Comment: Not really what I want to do. I'd like to change the styling of the tooltip to make it completely custom, not create a new element on tooltip click. Any solution?